# Can App Folders be moved inside iCloud Drive without disruption to their services?

Tags: icloud, finder

My iCloud Drive root folder is increasingly chaotic, with all my personal files and manually created folders mixed with all the automatically-created app folders — such as Sketch, TextEdit, Shortcuts, Pages, Garageband and many others.

My question is: can I move all of them to a manually created folder, such as "Apps" or something like this? Will this "break" my apps in any way?

Thank you.

Comment: This will for sure break those apps. Strange is the fact that they are showing on your iCloud drive. They should be hidden there. Are they appearing on Finder iCloud icon? If yes, then something wrong with Finder settings, what MacOS version are you using?

Comment: @Prado Are you sure about app libraries being hidden on iCloud Drive? That's been a staple of iCloud Drive since its inception for all my devices and across all the marketing material released by Apple (e.g. the first screenshot on [setting up iCloud Drive](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204025) by Apple)?

Comment: @grg Yes, they're clearly visible and even branded, and have been since the start. Also, these don't seem to be app "libraries" — they're just convenient locations used by apps to store user-created files.